# Possible to extend types in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Say I have the following type:

```
type Event = {
   name: string;
   dateCreated: string;
   type: string;
}
```

I now want to extend this type, i.e.

```
type UserEvent extends Event = {
   UserId: string; 
}
```

This doesn't work. How can I do this?

Comment: The `type` keyword is used to define [type aliases](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-4.html#type-aliases), not interfaces or classes.

Answer (score 1325, accepted):

The keyword `extends` can be used for interfaces and classes only.

If you just want to declare a type that has additional properties, you can use [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types):

```
type UserEvent = Event & {UserId: string}
```

**UPDATE** for TypeScript 2.2, [it's now possible to have an interface that extends object-like type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/13604), if the type satisfies some restrictions:

```
type Event = {
   name: string;
   dateCreated: string;
   type: string;
}

interface UserEvent extends Event {
   UserId: string; 
}
```

It does not work the other way round - `UserEvent` must be declared as interface, not a `type` if you want to use `extends` syntax.

And it's still impossible to use `extend` [with arbitrary types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27890) - for example, it does not work if `Event` is a type parameter without any constraints.

Comment: I am using TS v3.5.2, and I am not able to have an interface extend a type. 
`interface A<T> extends B<T> {blar}`
An interface can only extend an object type or intersection of object types with statically known members

Comment: @WORMSS doing this `interface Identifiable<T> extends T { id: string }` gives me error "An interface can only extend an object type or intersection of object types with statically known members.ts(2312)"

Comment: As typeScript is structurally typed, vs nominally, extending an 'arbitrary type' that has no further structure (constraints) will likely always be impossible.

Comment: @artem can we assign a value to some members while extending?
for example:
`interface UserEvent extends Event {
   name: 'test name';
   UserId: string;
}`

Comment: no the meaning of that is not what it seems - both `'test name'` and `string` here are types, not values - `'test name'` is a [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types). You can't assign values in the interfaces, you can assign values in classes but within the class, the syntax for assignment is `name = 'test name'`, and `name: 'test name'` within the class is again declaring a type, not assigning a value.

Comment: You could also in some cases want to use `|` when there isn't any overlap in the types but rather you want to have one more restrictive type and another that allows more types

Answer (score 132):

you can intersect types:

```
type TypeA = {
    nameA: string;
};
type TypeB = {
    nameB: string;
};
export type TypeC = TypeA & TypeB;
```

somewhere in you code you can now do:

```
const some: TypeC = {
    nameB: 'B',
    nameA: 'A',
};
```

Comment: This is a great solution. I'm working in React Native and this allows me to easily extend `TextInputProps` for my own custom text entry component. Thanks!

Comment: I'm a little confused by this, surely this TypeC a union?  I would expect an intersect of TypeA and TypeB would be {}? I.e. nothing in common?

Comment: @BenTaliadoros yes, its a bit confusing. [See this question & answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38855908/naming-of-typescripts-union-and-intersection-types)

Answer (score 34):

A generic extension type can be written as follows:

```js
type Extension<T> = T & { someExtensionProperty: string }
```

Comment: I would do something like this instead to make it truly generic:


`type Extension<T, E> = T & E;`

Answer (score 30):

What you are trying to achieve is equivalent to

```
interface Event {
   name: string;
   dateCreated: string;
   type: string;
}

interface UserEvent extends Event {
   UserId: string; 
}
```

The way you defined the types does not allow for specifying inheritance, however you can achieve something similar using intersection types, as [artem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/43848/artem) pointed out.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't like the word `interface` when I actually mean a `type`

Comment: Fair enough, then artem's answer should suit you :)

Answer (score 20):

You can also do that by using `type` in addition to `interface`:

```
type Event = {
   name: string;
   dateCreated: string;
   type: string;
}

type UserEvent = {
   UserId: string; 
} & Event
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a type defined with Union (more than one possible types) and you want to add an additional type, you can do something like this

```
interface TextInputProps = { type: string };
interface TextAreaProps  = { type: string | number };

export type InputCompProps = TextInputProps | TextAreaProps
```

to

```
interface CustomProps = { length: number };
export type InputCompProps = (TextInputProps | TextAreaProps) & CustomProps
```