# How to extend or reuse function type declorations?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

So I have a function that return a different value based on the inputs so far the type for this function has been

```
type func = (
  a: string, b:string, c:string, d:string, e:string, f:string, list?: boolean
) => string | string[]

const myFunction: func = require('./foo')
```

However this is not entirely correct, basically if `list = true` is passed return is `array` other wise its a `string`

So I rewrote the types

```
type func1 = (
  a: string, b:string, c:string, d:string, e:string, f:string
) => string

type func2 = (
  a: string, b:string, c:string, d:string, e:string, f:string, list: true
) => string[]

const myFunction: func1 & func2 = require('./foo')
const aa = myFunction('a','b','c','d','e','f') // string
const bb = myFunction('a','b','c','d','e','f', true) // string array
```

this works well however there is a crazy amount of redundancy. I know I cannot extend types, but Is there a trick similar to this

[Possible to extend types in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41385059/possible-to-extend-types-in-typescript)

that would allow me to use one `func1` type declaration when declaring `func2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just barely do this using the [new support for tuple types as rest parameter types in TypeScript 3.0](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-parameters-with-tuple-types):

```
type F<Rest extends any[], R> =
    (a: string, b: string, c: string, d: string, e: string, f: string, ...rest: Rest) => R;
type func1 = F<[], string>;
type func2 = F<[true], string[]>;
```

Comment: Cool! not using ts 3.0 yet but glad there's a way to do it down the line