# Typescript extract and create Union as a subset of a Union

Tags: typescript

I have the following Union type;

```
type MyUnionType = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz'
```

I would like to create a new Union `MySubUnion` as a subset;

```
type MySubUnion = 'foo' | 'bar'
```

I would like `MySubUnion` to be constrained to the values of its parent `MyUnionType`

```
type MySubUnion = 'foo' | 'bas' // => Error Type String 'b...
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Restricting a union to a subset of consituents is [subtyping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping).  In TypeScript, `A extends B` is a way of saying that `A` is a subtype of `B`.  (This seems backwards to some people at some times; by removing elements from a union, you are making the type more specific, which is a subtype.  The word "extends" might seem out of place, but that's what it is).

Unfortunately, you can't use `extends` to narrow type aliases the way you can with interfaces.  What you'd like to do is use following *invalid* syntax:

```
// this is not valid TypeScript, do not use this:
type MySubUnion extends MyUnionType = 'foo' | 'bar'; // should work
type MySubUnion extends MyUnionType = 'foo' | 'bas'; // should fail
```

But you can't do that.  As a workaround, you can make a new type function called `Extends<T, U>` which evaluates to `U` but only compile if `U` extends `T`, like this:

```
type Extends<T, U extends T> = U;
```

Then you can rewrite the invalid code to the following valid code:

```
type MySubUnion = Extends<MyUnionType, 'foo' | 'bar'>; // okay, compiles
```

and this:

```
type MySubUnion = Extends<MyUnionType, 'foo' | 'bas'>; // error:
// Type '"bas"' is not assignable to type 'MyUnionType'.
```

Does that help?  Good luck!

Comment: Extremely helpful thank you! I was not aware of type functions

Comment: Perfect, that was exactly what i was searching for! Thanks a LOT!

Comment: Why isn't the `Extends` function already included in TypeScript? Seems redundant to add it manually into every project when you just need to make a subset of a union of strings accepted somewhere.

Comment: They don’t add utility types to the language unless they need the types for emitting declaration files.  If you have more detailed questions then you might want to ask them in a new post instead of hoping that someone will respond to comments on answers to years-old questions. Good luck!

Answer (score 14):

Use the [Exclude<Type, Union>](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers) utility type.

```
type MyUnionType = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz'

type SubType = Exclude<MyUnionType, 'baz'>

// SubType is now 'foo' | 'bar'
```

Answer (score 4):

You could always flip the declaration order, though it's a bit odd with the particular names here.

```js
type MySubUnion = 'foo' | 'bar';
type MyUnionType = MySubUnion | 'baz';
```

It's more in the lines of composing union types.

Comment: Probably can't work if you don't not own `MyUnionType`.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in this post:

[Possible to extend types in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41385059/possible-to-extend-types-in-typescript)

You can just write like that:

```
type MySubUnion = MyUnionType & ('foo' | 'bar');
```

Comment: This works, but unfortunately does not warn/fail if you accidentally create a never type. E.g. `type MySubUnion = MyUnionType & 'someOtherLiteral'` will make `MySubUnion` be `never` without a warning.