# How to inherit all properties of a type into another type and some more

Tags: typescript

I have two types one inherits all the properties of other so I rewrite them all on the child. Is there a shortcut way to write this?

```
type Parent = {
  a: string,
  b: string
}

type Child = {
  a: string,
  b: string,
  c: number
}
```

Comment: `type Child = Parent & { ... }`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Possible to extend types in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41385059/possible-to-extend-types-in-typescript)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Possible to extend types in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41385059/possible-to-extend-types-in-typescript)

You can do like this :

```js
type Parent = {
  a: string,
  b: string
}

type Child = Parent & { c: number }
```