# React TypeScript - correct way to handle "incomplete" API responses

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rest

In our team we are creating a project with REST API backend and react + TypeScript frontend. After a few months of development we encountered a problem in the architecture. On the frontend we currently have a separate type created for each entity, e.g. student (simplified):

```
type TStudent = {
    firstName:string;
    lastName:string;
    friends:TStudent[];
    mainTeacher:TTeacher[];
}
```

The problem occurs when each of the API endpoints returns a different part of the data. e.g. the endpoint for the students table contains only `firstName` and `lastName` for the next endpoint then for example it returns only `firstName`,,`lastName`, `friends`. The example is very simplistic, in our case we are dealing with tens of multiple times nested types.

The problem is that we don't want to set the attributes of all types to optional, when we have a `UserTable` component, we want to use TypeScript to express that in the props is passed a user object which must necessarily have a first and last name, in the `UserDetail component we want to pass in the props the whole object with all parameters.

Could you advise me some elegant way to solve this problem with different responses from the API?

Please if you know some article where there is some nice architecture solving this problem?

I've Googled everywhere, not found single article solving this issue.

Comment: Sounds like you might want `zod`..  ->  https://zod.dev/

Comment: On a side note, type extensions would help you if you're dealing with different configurations of types across multiple contexts. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41385149/4378314

Comment: That's what utility types, namely `Pick`/`Omit` are for. You have a single type that's your **source of truth** for the typesystem and you build a lot of derived types that simply pick/omit some of the source type properties.

Comment: Agreeing with @WiktorZychla , here's a link to the TS docs for utility types. This is my most used section of the TS documentation by far. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html

Comment: As the others have described, you can use `Pick`/`Omit` to type everything you want correctly, and then if you want to combine those in a single object/state you'll probably grab some kind of state management solution. If you only call APIs at one place I would suggest just using something like `useReducer` to update different parts of the state, but if you need something more advanced take a look at some popular state management packages and chose one that fits your use case.