# Typescript subtracted type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, tsx

Is it somehow possible to create a subtracted type in Typescript?
I'm thinking of a user-case when a React component would expose just subset of if props to components user.
React-redux connect example:

```
import {Component, ComponentType} from 'react';

export function connect<S, A>(state: () => S, actions: A){
  return function createConnected<P>(component: ComponentType<P>){
    return class Connect extends Component<P-S-A>{ // <-- 
      // ...
    }    
  }
}
```

---

After reading:
[Exclude property from type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48215950/exclude-property-from-type)

Seems that I got this working...

```
import {Component, ComponentType} from 'react';

type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;

function connect<S, A>(state: () => S, actions: A) {
    return function createConnect<P extends S & A>(C: React.ComponentType<P>): ComponentType<Omit<P, keyof S | keyof A>> {
        return class Connect extends Component<Omit<P, keyof S | keyof A>> {
            // ...
        };
    };
}
```

.... But I don't understand how.

---

Update 2:

After playing with this some more, I discovered a cleaner way (in my opinion), to describe a subtracted type:

```
// LeftOuterJoin
type Subtract<T, V> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, keyof V>>;

function connect<S, A>(state: () => S, actions: A) {
    return function createConnect<P>(C: ComponentType<P>) {
        return class Connect extends Component<Subtract<P, S & A>> {
                  // ...
        };
    };
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exclude property from type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48215950/exclude-property-from-type). Using the `Omit` type from that question, you could write your type as `Omit<P, keyof S | keyof A>`

Answer (score 4):

> .... But I don't understand how.

Built-in [`Exclude`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#predefined-conditional-types) type is used here to operate on unions of string literals.

`Exclude<keyof T, K>` excludes all keys from `keyof T` which are in `K`, assuming that `K` is also a union of string literals - and the constraint `K extends keyof T` ensures that, declaring that `K` must be a subset of keys of `T`.

Another built-in type, [`Pick<T, K>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#partial-readonly-record-and-pick), allows to create a new type from T which has only the keys that are in `K` - again, assuming that `K` is a union of string literals and a subset of `keyof T`.

Using `Pick` and `Exclude` as building blocks, you can express type subtraction of one type from another as "pick only these properties from one type which are not present in another", with `Exclude` performing "not present" operation on keys.

Here it is in expanded form, making `ComponentProps` from `Props` excluding the props in either `S` or `A`:

```
type ComponentProps = Pick<Props, Exclude<keyof Props, keyof S | keyof A>>
```

Comment: It seems that `Exclude<keyof Props, keyof (S & A)>` works as well. The part `keyof S | keyof A`still does not make sense to me...

Comment: The two are equivalent. Imagine `{foo: string}` and `{bar: number}`, `keyof S -> 'foo'` and `keyof A -> 'bar'`, therefore, their union `keyof S | keyof A -> 'foo' | 'bar'`. The intersection `S & A -> {foo: string; bar: number}`, and the keyof of that is also `'foo' | 'bar'`.

Comment: @Nabuska yes `keyof (S & A)` is exactly the same type as `keyof S | keyof A`. Intersection type must have properties of all its member types, that is, its properties are union of properties of intersection members' types. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/38857724/43848