# Typescript - Union Types

Tags: typescript, union-types

I have created the following interface:

```
export interface Message{
  date: Timestamp | Date;
}

interface Timestamp {
  seconds: number;
  nanoseconds: number;
}
```

No idea why - I get the following error:

```
Property 'seconds' does not exist on type 'Date | Timestamp'.
Property 'seconds' does not exist on type 'Date'.
```

Why does the compiler searches for `seconds` in `Date` and doesn't work with the `Timestamp` type?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38857724/6680611).

Comment: What code actually produces that error?

Answer (score 2):

#### Short Answer

> Why does the compiler searches for seconds in Date and doesn't work with the Timestamp type?

When working with a union type, the compiler only allows access to properties **that exist on all the types**. Your error happens because `seconds` only exists on `Timestamp` and not also on `Date`.

#### Example

Here we create a `Message` that has a `Timestamp` for its `date`.

```
const message: Message = {
  date: {
    seconds: 10, 
    nanoseconds: 10
  }
}
```

In the following code, the compiler doesn't know that `date` is a `Timestamp`. As far as the compiler is concerned, `date` is either a `Date` or a `Timestamp`.

```
// Property 'seconds' does not exist on type 'Timestamp | Date'.
// Property 'seconds' does not exist on type 'Date'.
const seconds = message.date.seconds;
```

#### Type Guards

To give the compiler more information, we can add a type guard. Then the compiler will know that, inside the `if` statement, it is dealing with a `Timestamp`.

```
if (!(message.date instanceof Date)) { 
    // now we know we are dealing with a Timestamp
    // the compiler will not output an error
    const seconds = message.date.seconds;
}
```

Documentation on [type guards is here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html).