# Union and Intersection of types

Tags: typescript

For practice I wrote this code:

```
type Cat = {name: string, purrs: boolean};
type Dog = {name: string, barks: boolean, bites: boolean};

type CatOrDogOrBoth = Cat | Dog;
type CatAndDog = Cat & Dog;

let pet1 : CatOrDogOrBoth = {name: "pooky", purrs: true, bites: false};
let pet2 : CatAndDog = {name: "Timmy" };
```

But `TypeScript` compiler errors on **pet2** saying I need to add `purrs` to my object.
But isn't `CatAndDog` the intersection of those two types so only a **name** property ?

Comment: The intersection of two types `A & B` is a type `C` such that every `C` is an `A`, **and** every `C` is a `B`. For every `CatAndDog` to be a `Cat`, it must have a `purrs` property; no ifs, no buts. I think your confusion comes from assuming that the properties of the intersection type should be the intersection of the properties of the two original types; that is not generally true.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Naming of TypeScript's union and intersection types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38855908/naming-of-typescripts-union-and-intersection-types)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've got intersection and union backwards, which for some reason is not uncommon when people learn about TypeScript.  One probable cause for this confusion is that an object type is [*contravariant*](https://web.archive.org/web/20220823104433/https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/132/what-are-covariance-and-contravariance) in the type of its keys, so an intersection of object types has a union of its keys and vice versa.  That is, `keyof (Cat & Dog)` is the same as `(keyof Cat) | (keyof Dog)`, and `keyof (Cat | Dog)` is the same as `(keyof Cat) & (keyof Dog)`:

```
type KeyExploration = {
  keysOfIntersection: keyof (Cat & Dog) // "name" | "purrs" | "barks" | "bites"
  unionOfKeys: keyof Cat | keyof Dog // "name" | "purrs" | "barks" | "bites"
  keysOfUnion: keyof (Cat | Dog) // "name"
  intersectionOfKeys: (keyof Cat) & (keyof Dog) // "name"
}
```

Because of this contravariance, you will get intersections and unions mixed up if your conception of an object type is equivalent to its *set of declared properties*.  Instead, you should think about a type as a *set of allowed values* (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64246079/2887218) for more information).  And you should think of unions and intersections of types as unions and intersections of the sets of values assignable to those types.

For a [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) like `"foo"`, the set has a single element: { `"foo"` }.  For a type like `string`, it's the (practically) infinite set of all JavaScript strings: { `x` | `typeof x === "string"` } (using [set builder notation](https://www.mathsisfun.com/sets/set-builder-notation.html)).  And for object types like `{y: 0}`, it's also an infinite set: { `x` | `x.y === 0` }... that is, the set of all JavaScript objects with a `y` property exactly equal to `0`.

---

Another possible source of confusion is that object types in TypeScript are *open* and not *closed* or *exact* (see [microsoft/TypeScript#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936) for a request for exact types).

Object type definitions show which properties *must* be present, but they do not talk about which properties *must not* be present.  An object may have more properties than mentioned in its type's definition:

```
interface Garfield extends Cat {
  hatesMondays: true,
  eatsLasagna: true,
}
declare const garfield: Garfield;
const garfieldAsACat: Cat = garfield; // okay
```

(This is complicated a bit by the presence of [excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks), which treat *object literals* as if they were exact types.  But such checks are the exception and not the rule.)

Since object types are open, it means that the set of assignable values is larger than you might have thought.  Two object types like `{a: 0}` and `{b: 1}` actually have significant overlap; for example, the value `{a: 0, b: 1, c: 2, d: 3}` is assignable to both of them.

---

Now let's think about intersection (`&`) and union (`|`):

If I have an object of type `Cat & Dog`, it must be assignable to *both* `Cat` *and* `Dog`.  Because object types are open, nothing says that a `Cat` cannot have a `barks` or a `bites` property.  And nothing says that a `Dog` cannot have a `purrs` property.  So if you have something that is both a `Cat` and a `Dog`, it must have *all the properties of both types*.

```
let okay1: CatAndDog = 
  { name: "CatDog", purrs: true, bites: true, barks: true }; // Cat and Dog
```

And `pet2` fails because it's neither a `Cat` nor a `Dog`:

```
let pet2: CatAndDog = { name: "Timmy" }; // neither Cat nor Dog
```

On the other hand, an object of type `Cat | Dog` must only be assignable to *either* `Cat` *or* `Dog`.  If you assign a value to a variable of type `Cat | Dog` it needs to be at least one of those:

```
let okay1: CatOrDogOrBoth = 
  { name: "Sylvester", purrs: false }; // Cat
let okay2: CatOrDogOrBoth = 
  { name: "Odie", barks: true, bites: false }; // Dog
```

Your `pet1` is acceptable because it's a `Cat`.  It has an extra `bites` property, which is fine (and is not caught by excess property checking, although some people think it should (see [microsoft/TypeScript#20863](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20863)):

```
let pet1: CatOrDogOrBoth = 
  { name: "pooky", purrs: true, bites: false }; // Cat with bites:false
```

If I have an object of type `Cat | Dog` and I haven't yet inspected it in order to see which of `Cat` or `Dog` it is, the only safe property I can access is its `name`, because that's the only property I know for sure will be present.  It is *possible* that a `Cat | Dog` will have some properties from both types, as you show by your initialization of `pet1`, but you can't guarantee it.

---

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-UAMogLgANwsSVzdD2+g4lwAKCF6GxFM2Z6xiAADMN7bnIu77oeaYvnUURkiSf59HoZYmCWgFwMBNZgbUTZiC2kDAPinDdpCt6IfeyFPumKh1GAnA6BOeYAXhxYjAQQEgVOtSugA7nO-GlkJEDonJYjiEAA)