# Why is the type "never" meaningless in union types?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, union-types, typescript-types

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FA4FwTwBwUwAgJIDkAqBRASgZTQYRQgPJID6AgnALxwDOYATgJYB2A5nAGRzMwBuM9UOGjwAqkiKkK1OkzZwAPnABGAe1UAbGAENmi7nwFCgA)

I'm having some trouble while trying to wrap my head around the fact that the type `never` is meaningless and can be discarded when it's inside a **union type**.

I mean, I get that inside an **intersection type**, `never` will immediately make everything result in `never`, since no type can by some type and `never` at the same type. It makes sense to me.

[image]

But in an **union type**, my instinct initially tells me that the `never` type would be a valid option. My question is why isn't it? Why does `never` can be discarded in a union type?

[image]

Could anybody give a reasonable explanation about this so I can understand it better?

Comment: If you were using sets instead of types, then `string & never = never` is like `A ∩ ∅ = ∅` (where `∅` is the empty set) and `string | never = string` is like `A ∪ ∅ = A`. Or if you are using logical propositions, `string & never = never` is like `A ∧ ⊥ = ⊥` (where `⊥` is "false") and `string | never = string` is like `A ∨ ⊥ = A`.  Or if you really squint and use multiplication and addition, then `string & never = never` is like `a × 0 = 0` and `string | never = string` is like `a + 0 = a`.  Do you want the analogy spelled out as an answer? Or are you happy with the answer from VLRoyrenn below?

Comment: @jcalz:  Should be an answer. Was about to explain it using sets as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One way to think of a type is as a [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)) of all the values that are assignable to it.  So `boolean` can be thought of as {`true`, `false`}, the set containing just those two values.  And `string` can be thought of as the (essentially) infinite set containing every possible `string` value.

In TypeScript, `never` is the [bottom type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom_type).  It has *no* values.  If you have a JavaScript value and you ask "is this a value of type `never`?" then the answer is "no".  In terms of sets, `never` can be thought of as ∅, the
[empty set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_set).

In the mapping from types to sets-of-values, the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types) operation in TypeScript (`&`) can be thought of as the [set intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)#Intersections) operation (∩).  If you have sets A and B, then A∩B is the set of exactly the objects which are members of *both* A *and* B.  For any set A, the intersection A∩∅ with the empty set is just the empty set ∅.  There are no elements in both A and the empty set, since there are no elements in the empty set at all.  Back in TypeScript types, this means `A & never` becomes `never` for any type `A`.  It would be valid if the TypeScript compiler just left `string & never` as `string & never`, but in fact it goes ahead and reduces it to `never` automatically, since the latter representation is simpler.

On the flip side: in the mapping from types to sets-of-values, the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#union-types) operation in TypeScript (`|`) can be thought of as the [set union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)#Unions) operation (∪).  If you have sets A and B, then A∪B is the set of exactly the objects which are members of *either* A *or* B (this is an *inclusive* or).  For any set A, the union A∪∅ with the empty set is just A.  The union contains all the elements of A and all the elements of the empty set.  Since there are no elements of the empty set, that's just "all the elements of A". Back in TypeScript types, this means `A | never` becomes `A` for any type `A`.  It would be valid if the TypeScript compiler just left `string | never` as `string | never`, but in fact it goes ahead and reduces it to `string` automatically, since the latter representation is simpler.

So that's the basic explanation.  There are other analogies, such as boolean logic propositions like "this element is a member of this type" which is always FALSE for the `never` type, leading to things like A ∧ FALSE = FALSE and A ∨ FALSE = A.  Or like arithmetic, where the analogy isn't exact, but intersection looks like multiplication and union looks like addition (this analogy becomes exact for pairs instead of intersection and discriminated unions instead of regular unions) and the `never` type is 0.  But hopefully this gives enough intuition about why the compiler behaves this way.

Note that there's also a [top type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_type) in TypeScript called `unknown` which behaves exactly as the dual to `never` in that `A & unknown = A` and `A | unknown = unknown` and has the dual analog in set theory (the [universal set/class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universe_(mathematics))).  But you didn't ask about that and this answer is already long enough as it is.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation. Now it makes total sense to me. I think that what I was getting wrong was the fact that I was thinking of `string` as being "an actual string type" instead of a representation of all possible `string` types.

Answer (score 1):

Explained concretely, a variable of `type UNION_A = string | boolean | never` can take any valid value for a `boolean`, any valid value for a `string` and any valid value for `never` (of which no values can exist by definition), so a union with the `never` type adds nothing to the domain of values this variable may end up receiving.

**EDIT:** The point of the `never` type is that it's the type of something that cannot happen, usually the return type of function that can't possibly return.

```
function fail() {
    throw new Error(":(");
    // What is the *return* type of that function?
}

let foo = fail(); // foo can only receive the type never
console.log(foo * 2); // Doesn't matter what foo is, this is guaranteed to be dead code
```

There is no possible way for `fail()` to return a value, not even `null`. It can *never* return, so its return type is `never`, and any code that operates using the return value of that function is basically just dead code.

A union with never usually means you have this

```
function do_thing(x) {
    let foo;
    if (x == 0) {
        fail(); // foo is of type never
    } else {
        foo = 1/x; // foo is of type number
    }

    // Foo is technically of type number | never,
    // but you can discard never since it never runs.
    let bar = foo * 2;
    return bar;
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer but there's one issue. A return type of `never` is not inferred from a `throw` statement.

Comment: @AluanHaddad: Isn't it in Typescript? I've seen never be inferred in a number of other cases, and I know diverging functions are a common use case for that type in general, but that's actually surprising to hear. Serves me right for not double-checking.

Comment: This case is an odd one out. Inference of return types is usually more precise if anything than an explicit annotation and I take advantage of it in most cases.

Comment: What is `fail()`?  What is `Exception()`?  It helps when your code compiles in an IDE... but [this](https://tsplay.dev/4w1Ekw) has errors.  Do you mind editing the code here so that it works the way you're describing?

Comment: @jcalz: My bad, I keep forgetting that JS's default exception class is `Error`. Fixed the code so it's at least valid JS/TS.