# Retrieve subset of object where string values start with given string

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

Given an object

```
const MyObject = {
    a: 'a',
    b1: 'b1',
    b2: 'b2',
} as const;
```

I want to create a type for an object which only contains its string values which start with the letter `"b"`. How can I kind-of filter an object type by the contents of it's string values?

This is the type I want to construct out of `typeof MyObject`:

```
type OnlyBs = {
    b1: "b1";
    b2: "b2";
}
```

In an attempt to get the desired solution, I used [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) and the `infer` keyword:

```
type OnlyBs = {
    [K in keyof typeof MyObject]: typeof MyObject[K] extends `b${infer Rest}` ? `b${Rest}` : never;
};
```

This, however, gives me the type

```
type OnlyBs = {
    readonly a: never;
    readonly b1: "b1";
    readonly b2: "b2";
}
```

which is close to what I want, but not the desired type. Hence, using it here with an object `MyObject2` gives me the type error:

```
const MyObject2: OnlyBs = {
    b1: 'b1',
    b2: 'b2',
};
```

> "Property 'a' is missing in type '{ b1: "b1"; b2: "b2"; }' but required in type 'OnlyBs'.(2741)"

The issue is that TypeScript requires me to add the `a` property, although its type is `never`. I can't come up with another way to achieve my goal. I feel like I'm close but I can't get the entire property (including its key) removed from the resulting object type.

**Btw:** In case it's easier to do, a solution which constrains the objects' keys (instead of the property values) would also work for me because in this particular example the property values equal the property keys.

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAsgTwPICMBWBTYsC8MDeAUDCTAIYBcMA5GdQDTGkoCMV1rDTJKATO3y4BfchBihIUANyFCUBAAcMMJGAA2CAEJi8RUjADaAaRgBLMDADWGBCABmMeUvvxk6LFAC6VJxheJUTGxjTxgMAA8oDDAAEzEAAxQAEnxzOwwAJxgAJQxoIXiYAH4YRJTc-MKqMAwAN0yZIRkAemaYABUAC1MxDLyAVzUoMXNHTuVfCkJWx0VlVQ1tGF1ptv0%20shjwDXJquobV-RgNrfUEGFYqACJWK5a10hPt875rvjvDoVkJaFdAj34KjOSxW%20kuNE4jDBgI4vGEMiAA) of my code example

Comment: Try to return K in OnlyBs instead of `b${Rest}`. In this way, OnlyBs returns allowed keys. Then just use Pick to obtain desired props

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to return `K` in `OnlyBs` instead of `b${Rest}`. In this way, OnlyBs returns allowed keys. Then just use Pick to obtain desired props.

Consider this example:

```js
const MyObject = {
    a: 'a',
    b1: 'b1',
    b2: 'b2',
} as const;

type AllowedKeys<Obj> = {
    [K in keyof Obj]: Obj[K] extends `b${infer _}` ? K : never; // <-- use K instead of `b{infer Rest}`
}[keyof Obj]; // use extra keyof Obj

{
    // "b1" | "b2" <-- allowed keys
    type _ = AllowedKeys<typeof MyObject>

}

type OnlyBs<Obj> = Pick<Obj, AllowedKeys<Obj>>

{
    // readonly b1: "b1";
    // readonly b2: "b2";
    type _ = OnlyBs<typeof MyObject>
}

const MyObject1: OnlyBs<typeof MyObject> = {
    b1: 'b1',
    b2: 'b2',
}; // ok

const MyObject2: OnlyBs<typeof MyObject> = {
    a: null as any, // expected error
    b1: 'b1',
    b2: 'b2',
};
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/Wk5QlN)

If you want to make it in one utility type, consider this:

```js
type AllowedKeys<Obj> = Pick<Obj, {
    [K in keyof Obj]: Obj[K] extends `b${infer _}` ? K : never;
}[keyof Obj]>;
```

---

> Why does [keyof Obj] at the end of the mapped type AllowedKeys not also retrieve "a"? What's this concept called? Without [keyof Obj] and a call of keyof later, "a" would be there.

Let's remove `[keyof Obj]`:

```js
const MyObject = {
    a: 'a',
    b1: 'b1',
    b2: 'b2',
} as const;

type AllowedKeys<Obj> = {
    [K in keyof Obj]: Obj[K] extends `b${infer _}` ? K : never; // <-- use K instead of `b{infer Rest}`
};

{
    // {
    //     readonly a: never;
    //     readonly b1: "b1";
    //     readonly b2: "b2";
    // }
    type _ = AllowedKeys<typeof MyObject>
}
```

As you might have noticed, we are getting an object where if value exists it is allowed key. If key is not allowed it is `never`. This is why `a` is `never`. Now. let's try to use square bracket notation with our result. It works for types in the same way as it works for runtime values in plain js:

```js
{
    // {
    //     readonly a: never;
    //     readonly b1: "b1";
    //     readonly b2: "b2";
    // }
    type a = AllowedKeys<typeof MyObject>['a'] // never
    type b = AllowedKeys<typeof MyObject>['b1'] // b1, because keys and allowed values are the same
    type ab = AllowedKeys<typeof MyObject>['a' | 'b1'] // still "b1" because any union with never does not make any sense
}
```

As you see, `ab` type returns `b1` instead of `b1 | never`. Why? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64230626/why-is-the-type-never-meaningless-in-union-types) you will find an answer. Hence using `AllowedKeys<typeof MyObject>[keyof typeof MyObject]` retuns `b1 | b2` because TS compiler removes `never`.

One more thing, return union type is not a union of keys, it is a union of object values.

Here you have an utility type to obtain a union of all object values: `type Values<T>=T[keyof T]`

Comment: Why does `[keyof Obj]` at the end of the mapped type `AllowedKeys<Obj>` not also retrieve `"a"`? What's this concept called?
Without `[keyof Obj]` and a call of `keyof` later, `"a"` would be there. [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAsgTwPICMBWBTYsC8MDeAUDCTAIYBcMA5GdQDTGkoCMV1rDTJKATO3y4BfchBihIUANyFCUBAAcMMAIIAbNSADuGACYBpDAggAeVGgB8MPEVIwA2vpgBLMDADWRkADMY5gLpU5o7+MBgAHlAYYLpiAAYoACT4rt4YAE4wAPpCcTAA-DBOVGAYAG4ZUjAA9NUwJgC0DTAArhDKTq7QGGS6MD4wCSlgaZkAShjQuYRCVbUwWs5QABYgLbARUOlkHl6+5rK2pPMARGQnMAA+MCesF9e3vBeNzWQa2nq7xtww8krZ1i+A3Umh0BiMpj+GAGiHMWCgFlkQkIQA)

Comment: @Andru I made an update. Hope it is clear now

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the thorough explanation! That now makes complete sense! Via `[keyof Obj]` (which in this example is `['a' | 'b1' | 'b2']`) you're creating a union and thereby the union member with the type `never` gets removed. Cool!

Answer (score 2):

A solution to constrain the object's **keys** (and not the values) in case the property keys and property values are the same strings.

This will pick only the properties where the keys begin with a `"b"` letter (`MyObject` as defined in the question):

```
type OnlyBKeys = {
    [K in keyof typeof MyObject as K extends `b${infer _}` ? K : never]: typeof MyObject[K];
};
```

or a generic variant for arbitrary prepended strings:

```
type KeyStartsWith<Object extends object, Prepend extends string> = {
    [K in keyof Object as K extends `${Prepend}${infer _}` ? K : never]: Object[K];
};
```

This can be used as:

```
const MyObject3: KeyStartsWith<typeof MyObject, 'b'> = {
    b1: 'b1',
    b2: 'b2',
};
```

[TS Playground of solution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAsgTwPICMBWBTYsC8MDeAUDCTAIYBcMA5GdQDTGkoCMV1rDTJKATO3y4BfchBihIUANyFCUBAAcMMJGAA2CAEIBpDAjF4ipGAG1tMAJZgYAaz0gAZjHlLH8ZOiywyY8xgAeUBhgACZiAAYoACT4Vg4YAE4wAPpC4TAA-DDmVGAYAG6JALpULhhuiKiY2GZFMkIyhBLQ7lVe-CrqWrr6MIbcMKwCLFzGfAK8wo0A9NMwAIJiAObBiRbAcorKAMpQZAlQEADqFlAAFgA8bdgwAUGhYiCe2PQwAAoJGEqht4HBYTBoAkrEsAHx9AgDMyWax2BBua7eXy-e4A8IxD5ff5CGJxRIpNKZbIwXIFYpURG1eqNIykWbOLYpCG0kj04yfMghcAaQZsGAAIlY-JkxjZpA5XK6gw6gt4woG9KEAzKTLwu32hxO5wuZQqHmqUFeHGooPqsmasEqzygAGYqOqDsdTpddU4rQajSgTcyBkMaJxGGMOhxJowGoQgA)

Comment: Nice solution! I think it worth adding link to [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as)