# TypeScript: Why is undefined not an option if type is a union of empty array and array of data when accessing an item

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Can anyone explain this?

Why is undefined not an option if type is a union of empty array and array of data when accessing an item

```
type emptyArray = []
type accessEmptyArray = emptyArray[0] // returns undefined

type validData = {id:number, name:string}
type someData = validData[] | []

type test = someData[0] // returns type validData but could also be undefined
```

I assume I can solve this by using an assertion but it will make my code quite verbose.

I'm quite surprised by this issue as it seems like a problem that is easily overlooked and the type of problem that TS is built to solve but maybe I haven't thought of a downside to my assumed way of it working

Example: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBBC2agIICdkEMRQLxQNoF0AoUSKNAY3IgGdqBReJVDbGRkFdEXABnygD0AqMgjAArsgB21KOKkATCADMAllIgLCxcNABuaADaqFAETTA0rAN4mAXFPGwARhGQAaKFLSwId6sDI6gDmAL46pNQA9r7mlqwGxmYWaARQAD54RBHQwDTArNGxKbz8QiJikjJQJPpGJnFWzuIF5FHihgpkhtFQrnKKKuqahEA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[That's as design](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/39560).

Indexed access on a type will not return undefined.

```
type array = Array<string>;
type firstItemType = array[0] // string;
```

Comment: Thanks @matthieu-riegler, noUncheckedIndexedAccess is exactly what I need. My code has lit up with red all over it - but it's a price I'm willing to pay!

Answer (score 0):

In order to understand that, please be aware that :

```js
type EmptyArray = []
type EmptyArray2 = never[]
```

both `EmptyArray` and `EmptyArray2` are equal. Empty array, in TypeScript is infered as `never[]`.

Try this:

```js
type EmptyArray = []
type Item = EmptyArray[number] // never
```

Hence, union of both empty and non empty looks like this:

```js
type ValidData = { id: number, name: string }

type Union = Array<ValidData> | never[]

type NonEmptyElement = Array<ValidData>[number] // ValidData
type EmptyElement = never[][number]             // never

type Result = Union[0] // ValidData | never -> ValidData
```

When you make union of empty / non empty array and trying to obtain first element, you basically obtaining union of `ValidData | never`, which is equal to just `ValidDate`.

If you are curious why `never` is meaningless in any union, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64230626/why-is-the-type-never-meaningless-in-union-types)

---

As for the error in:

```js
type emptyArray = []

type accessEmptyArray = emptyArray[0] // returns undefined
```

This is because `emptyArray` does not have any elements, and type script does not allow even to use `0`, however, you are still allowed to use index of Array:

```js
type accessEmptyArray = emptyArray[number] // never
```

This is because `Array` has this type signature:

```js
interface Array<T> {
  [n: number]: T
}
```

Comment: The union is not the cause here : ` type array = Array<string>;
type firstItemType = array[0] // string; `

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler but OP has provided an empty array as literal array: `[]` which is equal to `Array<never>` and it can't be comparable to `Array<string>`. This is different case

Comment: Thanks a lot @captain-yossarian-from-ukraine there's definitely some interesting things explained in there but I really need undefined, not never. Using noUncheckedIndexedAccess compilerOption in the tsconfig will work for me. Thanks again!

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler you are right, it seems that I completely missed the point. Upvote from me