# Typescript error on extending String Literal Types

Tags: typescript

I have two String Literal Types and I am trying to create a third one by extending these two Types.
But Typescript gives error.

If I try the same with Object Types it works fine.

What is the reason?  Any workaround?

```
export type T1 = 'ONE' | 'UNO';
export type T2 = 'TWO' | 'DOS';

export type O1 = {prop1: string};
export type O2 = {prop2: string};

export type T3 = T1 & T2;

export type O3 = O1 & O2;

const value:T3 = 'ONE'; // ERROR: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'

const value2: O3 = {prop1: '1', prop2: '2'}; // no error
```

Comment: Changing the & to | works i.e. export type T3 = T1 & T2;
But then same should apply to objects also.

Comment: What, specifically, is your goal here?  It is possible to have a value assignable to both  `{prop1: string}` and `{prop2: string}`, since those two types are not mutually exclusive... but it is impossible to have a value assignable to both `"ONE"` and `"TWO"`, which are two distinct string literals.  I think you misunderstand how intersections and unions work on object types.  Let me see if I can find a canonical q/a for this

Comment: Okay, check out [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59722333/union-and-intersection-of-types).  I think this is probably a duplicate of that one, but if you don't think so, then please edit this question to highlight the difference.

Comment: don't you wanted to do `export type T3 = T1 | T2;` , then value could be either 'ONE' or  'TWO'.   `&` doesn't make sense in your case