# Convert Union type to Intersection type

Tags: typescript, types, union, intersection

I'm trying to convert a union type to an intersection type:

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> = // unknown code

type test = UnionToIntersection<{a: 1} | { b: 2}>
// typeof test should be {a: 1} & { b: 2}, an impossible type
```

This is just one step in a larger type function which will then merge the properties of `{a:1}` and `{b:2}` to make `{a:1, b:2}`.  But that's a later step.

**First step is I need to convert my union to an intersection.  How can I do that?**

---

For those wondering, it will then go into this:

```
export type SubpropertyMerge<T> = (
  T extends (...args: infer A) => infer R ? (
    (...args: A) =>  R
  ): (
    T extends object ? (
      T extends string | number | ((...args: any) => any) | symbol | boolean ? T
      : { [K in keyof T]: SubpropertyMerge<T[K]> }
    ) : T
  )
);

// SubpropertyMerge<{a: 1} & { b: 2}> === {a:1, b:2}
```

Comment: I'm inclined to close this as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type) unless you can articulate a difference.  Side note: `{a: 1} & {b: 2}` is not an impossible type, and it is equivalent to `{a:1, b: 2}`... maybe [you have this confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59722333/union-and-intersection-of-types)?

Comment: I over simplified my situation.  The "impossible" type is `{ foo: {a :1}} & { foo: {b: 2}}`, because foo will become never... or something of that nature.  I haven't figured out the exact point at which intersections stop being... unintuitive to me specifically.

Comment: [That's not impossible either](https://tsplay.dev/wOaZEm).  Impossible types equivalent to `never` do exist, but I haven't seen any here yet.

Comment: Last try: `{ a:1 } & { a:2 }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `UnionToIntersection` type:

```
export type UnionToIntersection<U> = (
  U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never
) extends (k: infer I) => void
  ? I
  : never
```

Comment: This worked for a case where the type for U was specified.  Unfortunately, my type for U is some other generic which extends a known type and that was just enough to break some things involving inference from it.