# Union operator in interface and TypeScript error 2339

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is it possible to combine inside interface other interfaces like:

```
interface IList {
  list: IData[] | IData2[];
  flow: SelectedTab;
}
```

IData and IData2 are with different params.
So it should (correct me if I'm wrong) take params from IData **or** IData2.
Conditionally I'm passing an array with objects for IData or IData2.

But TypeScript says:

> Property 'language' does not exist on type 'IDataLanguageCountry | IDataCurrency'.
> Property 'language' does not exist on type 'IDataCurrency'.ts(2339)

Code to reproduce:

```
interface IData { data1: string }
interface IData2 { data2: string }
const list: IData[] | IData2[] = []

for (const item of list) {
  item.data1 // error
}
```

So it means I can't do this or am I doing something wrong?
Any ideas how to "fix" it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59722333/union-and-intersection-of-types does this help?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @AlexWayne sorry, didn't know how to show the exact problem.

Comment: @TusharShahi not really. I've tried using type, but it didn't help.

Comment: please provide a minimum reproducable example. With the given code, we cannot reproduce the error.

Comment: Is [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBE5jsg3sgEyzgEYAuZAZzClAHNkBfAKFElkRQ2ICY9DeFarRAMWzBAHsQ1ZABtg1Ct2wBtALrIAPmkzYeG5AF5kG5sxiSoyABRSZYZMEgBbZJJjzFYAJR5myIFOrgB0RNgkyAD0UcjQUFbMLEA) the same issue?

Comment: @AlexWayne yeah! it is.

Comment: So are you really asking for `Partial<IData & IData2>[]`? Or `Xor<IData, IData2>[]`?

Comment: @caTS one component, with the same rendering approach but with a different data structure described in those interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before using either `data1` or `data2` you need to prove to the TS compiler which one of either of your types you really have:

```
interface IData { data1: string }
interface IData2 { data2: string }
const list: IData[] | IData2[] = []

for (const item of list) {
  if ("data1" in item)
    item.data1
  // ^? IData
  if ("data2" in item)
    item.data2
  // ^? IData2
}
```

[tsplayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBE5jsg3sgEyzgEYAuZAZzClAHNkBfAKFElkRQ2ICY9DeFarRAMWCAPYhqyADbBqFbtgDaAXWQAfNJmw91yALzJ1zZjAlRkACknSwyYJAC2yCTDkKwASjzNkjh7WAERE2CTBjiCOLt7+ATEQzgB0YaTxAPQZyAB6APzxwEGhvJGgic5xCRWpvJnZ+cyMQA)

See handbook: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html