# Intersection types doesn't work properly?

Tags: typescript

Why next code doesn't work? I assumed that intersection type **A & B** should match either **A** or **B**.

```
type Id = number | string;
type EntityType<T> = T & { id: Id };

const fn = <T>(a: EntityType<T>) => { }

const fn2 = <T>() => {
    const f = fn<T>({ id: 5 }); // this line causes error
}
```

Link to reproduce:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=7&ssc=27&pln=7&pc=32#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgJlAvFAdgVwLYCMICcoA+UAzsLgJYoDmA3ALABQokUAoisOaACrgQA83AHxIo3KADIoAbyjk4ALlgIAvvQaMAxgHsUpKADMUowUIAUAQyXtOPPqYCUSEbJWMtu-UYBMJ4WadEF0YoUKgdPWBDUSNTM1l5JQBWKBUHdTcNLMYgA

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Naming of TypeScript's union and intersection types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38855908/naming-of-typescripts-union-and-intersection-types)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the generic type from the function call:

```
type Id = number | string;
type EntityType<T> = T & { id: Id };

const fn = <T>(a: EntityType<T>) => { };

const fn2 = <T>() => {
    const f = fn({ id: 5 }); // this line causes error
}
```

Also see:
[could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'object'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505560/could-be-instantiated-with-a-different-subtype-of-constraint-object)