# Interface vs Types : intersection and union of properties and values

Tags: typescript

I have been reading book effective typescript and there is this paragraph there with code which is not clear to me :

1.

```
  interface Person {
      name: string;
    }
    interface Lifespan {
      birth: Date;
      death?: Date;
    }
    
    type PersonSpan = Person & Lifespan; // why not never type ?
```

The `&` operator computes the intersection of two types. What sorts of values belong to
the PersonSpan type?

On first glance the Person and Lifespan interfaces have no
properties in common, so you might expect it to be the empty set (i.e., the never
type). **But type operations apply to the sets of values (the domain of the type), not to
the properties in the interface.** And remember that values with additional properties
still belong to a type. So a value that has the properties of both Person and Lifespan
will belong to the intersection type:

```
const ps: PersonSpan = {
 name: 'Alan Turing',
 birth: new Date('1912/06/23'),
 death: new Date('1954/06/07'),
}; // OK
```

2. what if declare

   type newPersonSpan = Person | Lifespan; // what are the possible values we can assign now ?

could someone please explain this in more layman language

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Naming of TypeScript's union and intersection types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38855908/naming-of-typescripts-union-and-intersection-types)

Comment: thanks ...going through the link ...looks pretty helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short version is: to be a `Person & Lifespan`, an object must have all the properties defined in `Person`, and it must also have all the properties defined in `Lifespan`.

Long version: The book is describing one way you can conceptualize the way that `&` works: as the intersection of sets. First, let's start with what this means:

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
}
```

To be a `Person`, a variable must be an object, and that object must have a name property that is a `string`. Simple enough, but it's important to point out: *it can also have any number of extra properties, and still be a `Person`*. So all of the following objects are compatible with `Person`:

```
{ name: 'bob' }
{ name: 'alice', age: 30 }
{ name: 'eve', birth: new Date() }
```

You can think of types as being [mathematical sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)), in which case `Person` is the set of the 3 objects i just listed, plus every other possible object that would match the definition. All objects that have a string for a name, plus any number of extra properties of any type.

Similarly, `Lifespan` can also be thought of as a set. To be in the `Lifespan` set, an object must have a `birth` property which is a Date, and if it has a `death` property, that property must also be a Date. And as before, any number of extra properties are allowed

Examples of Lifespans include:

```
{ birth: new Date(), death: new Date() }
{ birth: new Date(), name: true }
{ name: 'eve', birth: new Date() }
```

The `&` operator finds the intersection of two sets. Some objects are in `Person`, some are in `Lifespan`, and some are in both; the intersection means the ones that are in both.

[image]

So from the examples i gave, `{ name: 'eve', birth: new Date() }` is in the intersection. It is both a Person, and a Lifespan. The rest of the examples are only in one, not the other, for one reason or another. Eg, `{ name: 'bob' }` is not a Lifespan because it has no birth, and `{ birth: new Date(), name: true }` is not a Person because its name is the wrong type.

Comment: thanks @nicolas 

the possible set of values and then their intersection helped me understand this very well

Comment: there is this link also which is pretty useful .

Reading from this explain this line "But type operations apply to the sets of values (the domain of the type), not to
the properties in the interface"

https://medium.com/@1jpablo1/illustrated-guide-to-types-sets-and-values-8093d0b7d648

Answer (score 1):

Think about it this way:

1. There are many entities named Mickey.
2. There are many mice.
3. Mickey Mouse is in the set that is the intersection of both the set of Mickies and the set of mice.

It works the same way for `Person` and `Lifespan`: there's a set of types that are Persons and there's a set of types that are Lifespans and there's an an intersection of types that are *both* Persons *and* Lifespans.

Remember that Typescript is structurally typed. If I have a type Foo and a type Bar

```ts
type Foo = { a: number };
type Bar = { b: string };
```

then *any* object with an `a` property that's a number counts as a `Foo`, and *any* object with a `b` property that's a string counts as a `Bar`, and a `Foobar` (`Foo & Bar`) is any object that is both a `Foo` and a `Bar`, i.e. has an `a: number` and a `b: string`.